# Combining yerrorbars and variable point size

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot the following data file

```
#x  y   s   err
1   1   0.1 0.2
2   2   0.2 0.2
3   3   0.3 0.2
4   4   0.4 0.2
5   5   0.5 0.2
6   6   0.6 0.2
7   7   0.7 0.2
8   8   0.8 0.2
9   9   0.9 0.2
10  10  1.0 0.2
```

where the points have a variable size given by column 3 and the errors are given in column 4. I can get

```
plot "test" u 1:2:3 pt 7 ps variable
plot "test" u 1:2:4 w yerrorbars pt 7
```

to work independently, giving me this:

[image]

But when I try to combine them

```
plot "test" u 1:2:4:3 w yerrorbars pt 7 ps variable
```

I get something very strange:

[image]

`yerrorbars` seems to be using column 4 as the y column and column 3 as the yerror column. Even stranger, I get the same output if I try `u 1:2:3:4`. Is there something wrong with how I'm doing this? I can manually draw the errorbars as vectors, but I'd prefer to use the built-in errorbars style if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gnuplot> help yerrorbars

 The `yerrorbars` (or `errorbars`) style is only relevant to 2D data plots.
 `yerrorbars` is like `points`, except that a vertical error bar is also drawn.
 At each point (x,y), a line is drawn from (x,y-ydelta) to (x,y+ydelta) or
 from (x,ylow) to (x,yhigh), depending on how many data columns are provided.
 The appearance of the tic mark at the ends of the bar is controlled by
 `set errorbars`.

      2 columns:  [implicit x] y ydelta
      3 columns:  x  y  ydelta
      4 columns:  x  y  ylow  yhigh

 An additional input column (4th or 5th) may be used to provide information
 such as variable point color.
```

So in order to provide more than 3 columns and still use a single value for the ydelta, you should be able to do

```
plot "test" u 1:2:($2-$4):($2+$4):3 w yerrorbars pt 7 ps variable
```

**However**, as you point out this doesn't actually work as documented.

**Work-around**

An alternative is to make two passes; first plot the errorbar lines and suppress the points, second plot the point with the desired properties :

```
unset key
plot "test" u 1:2:3 with yerrorbars pt 0, \
         "" u 1:2:4 with points pt 7 ps variable
```

[image]

Comment: Ah ok. It was the final line `An additional input column (4th or 5th) may be used to provide information such as variable point color.` that led me to believe the 4th column could be used for variable point size.

Comment: I just checked, and this answer does not actually work (5.4 patchlevel 3) - the errorbars are now plotted correctly, but the point size is not variable

Comment: Huh. You are right.  There is a bug of some sort.  I will note that in the answer and investigate further.

Comment: I can't believe I thought of using two passes using nohead vectors instead of yerrorbars like in your workaround... I'll open a bug report (e: ah oops I didn't realise you're one of the project maintainers on sourceforge)